# Wait for API result to be returned in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

Say I have a function which returns the result on an input after 1 sec:

```
function slowDouble(num) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        return num * 2;
    }, 1000);
}
```

Now I want to call this function and wait until the result is returned, so I can do other operations on it. I tried to wrap this function in a `Promise` but the result is returned to then block after the `log` statement is executed (printing `undefined`):

```
function promisify(num) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        var res = slowDouble(num);
        resolve(res);
    });
}

function promisifyTest(num) {
    promisify(num).then((res) => {
        console.log('then result ', res);
    })
}

promisifyTest(4); // undefined
```

Then I tried to use `await`:

```
async function asyncCallToAPI(num) {
    var tt = await promisify(num);
    console.log('async result', tt);
}

asyncCallToAPI(3); // undefined
```

and got the same `undefined` result back.
I know this is very similar to other questions asked here but I couldn't figure this out yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39495551/add-delay-to-javascript-method-that-returns-promise

Comment: @estus My question is actually about handling the delay not making the delay.

Comment: I see. The problem is that slowDouble is originally wrong. You can't return anything from setTimeout callback. slowDouble should initially use promises or callbacks in some other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not properly wrapping the `setTimeout` into a promise.  Your `slowDouble` doesn't return anything.  That's why you get `undefined`.  You need to change how you wrote this so that the `slowDouble` function returns a promise, and you can get rid of the `promisify` function.

The difference is when you're constructing a promise, you need to be able to call the `resolve` callback from within the callback for whatever asynchronous function you're trying to wrap.  In the case of `setTimeout`, we need to call `resolve` from within the callback to `setTimeout`.

```js
function slowDouble(num) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(num * 2), 1000);
  });
}

async function promisifyTest(num) {
  const result = await slowDouble(num);
  console.log('Async result:', result);
}

console.log('Waiting...');
promisifyTest(4);
```