# Is it possible to call an async function inside a constructor in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous

I have an async function named `async a()` which has to be run before function `componentDidMount()`.

So how can I call an async function inside a constructor?
Because the constructor function gets run before the componentDidMount function.

I need to be sure my `async a()` completes first in the constructor and then all methods within componentDidMount are executed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't do it inside constructor, because constructor can't wait for `await`
So you can have another function(for example `b()`) for all the processes you want to run after `async a()`. And you have two choice for doing this:

1- use `async/await`:

```
async componentDidMount() {  
    try {
      await a();  // it will wait here untill function a finishes
    } catch(err) {}

    b(); // after function a finished, this function will calls
}
```

2- using `.finally`:

```
componentDidMount() {
    // in below line, function `a` will call, and when it finishes, the function inside `.finally` will be notified
    a().finally(() => {
        b(); // now your function `a` finished and you can call extra process in function `b`
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi I've tested this in a simple javascript file but the result is like this:
async function a() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('A');
    }, 2000);
}

async function b() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('B')
    }, 1000);
}

function c() {
    console.log("C");
}


async function componentDidMount() {
    await a();
    await b();
    c();
}

componentDidMount();

C
B
A

Comment: please refer to the last answer because in comment the code does not looks well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55025299/is-it-possible-to-call-an-async-function-inside-a-constructor-in-react-native/55030292#55030292

Answer (score 13):

Asynchronous constructor is a potential antipattern because it doesn't result in behaviour that is expected from it.

Asynchronous side effects are supposed to happen after a component is mounted and thus occur in `componentDidMount`, this is what it's for. It's impossible to delay the lifecycle of a component and it's incorrect to think about it in these terms.

It's supposed to work like:

```
class Foo extends Component
  async a() {...}

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.a();
  }

  render() {
    (conditionThatIsTrueWhenThereResult) ? (
      <div>...the result from a...</div>
    ) : (
      <div>fallback</div>
    );
  }
}
```

If it's necessary to keep a component synchronous, `a` asynchronous side effect should be moved to parent component that renders a child only when the result from `a` is ready to use.

Comment: I've searched about making async function componentDidMount and most of people do not suggested to make async the function componentDidMout like you made it.
Please make sure me that using async componentDidMount() is a good way or not.

Comment: *most of people do not suggested to make async the function componentDidMout like you made it.* - who? It's either this, or doing `a()` in parent component and providing the result through props. Both ways are acceptable.

Comment: thank you to comment and I am sorry that my English is not well
I mean in answer to my question you put async keyword befor componentDidMount fucntion and there I dont know it will affect on performance issue weather or not.

Comment: because Most of people in internet do not suggested to use async keyword before componentDidMount

Comment: I doubt that there's a lot of people who would emphasize this idea because this is not a big deal. Any way, this suggestion is wrong. `async` doesn't affect the performance, it affects componentDidMount's return value. This is roughly the same thing as `componentDidMount() { return this.a() }`. The method returns a promise this way, this makes the component more testable and extendable. It's correct to return a promise for chaining anywhere where promises are used, unless this causes problems (and in this case this doesn't cause them).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55025299/is-it-possible-to-call-an-async-function-inside-a-constructor-in-react-native/55030292#55030292

Answer (score 1):

Call `a()` in componentDidMount like so:

```
async componentDidMount() {
       await a();
       otherFuncions()
}
```

`otherFunctions()` will only be executed after `a()` is completed

Comment: async componentDidMount(){} will have their own risk.
I would not suggest to make async the componentDidMount func
and also I need to completed finish all a() function task befor componentDidMount execute.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55025299/is-it-possible-to-call-an-async-function-inside-a-constructor-in-react-native/55030292#55030292

Answer (score 1):

Async work in constructor is a no no.

Typically you would either have a component that renders a spinner and triggers an async call. Then you can update this component to render something else once the async call is finished.

Another solution is to push that logic up to whoever is rendering this component. The parent should trigger the async call and render the component only after the async call.

---

As others suggested, you could use `componentDidMount` from the component lifecycle to handle this.
See: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi every one I've test all code you have answered but still there the result is like below

```
async function a() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('A');
    }, 2000);
}

async function b() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('B')
    }, 1000);
}

function c() {
    console.log("C");
}


async function componentDidMount() {
    await a();
    await b();
    c();
}

componentDidMount();
```

Output: 
***C
B
A***

**As you said here A and B should be finish first then the last non async function. A**

Comment: `a` and `b` resolve immediately. You don't have a promise to chain inside them. In case you want to mimic a delay, it should be `async function a() { await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve), 2000)); console.log('A') }` . See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39496056/3731501

Comment: async functions only will wait if there is `await` inside them or if you return `Promise` inside them

Comment: in your example you just setTimeout and both your functions `a` and `b` will resolve before your timeout finish

Answer (score -1):

use `UNSAFE_componentWillMount()` or `componentWillMount()` or better read this https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount
or please search what is constructor.