# For loop not waiting for await

Tags: node.js

I am using the "for of" loop. But still, it's not waiting for the dummy function to exit. I was under the assumption that await would wait for the "dummy" function to finish and then use "for of".

Log output:

```
End wait true
starting wait
End wait true
starting wait
End wait true
I am waiting for 925.6301720227887
I am waiting for 923.6969211579702
I am waiting for 962.0987671698102
etc...



const dummy = async(timeToWait) => {
    await setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("I am waiting for", timeToWait);

    }, timeToWait);
    return Promise.resolve(true);
}

    // Iterate over the minutes off and get aggregate data
    const computeAggregate = async (model, sym) => {


    await model.find({"symbol": sym})
    .sort({trade_ts:1}).exec()
    .then(async (symbol) => {
        var firstDoc = symbol[0];
        currentMinute = symbol[0].minutes_offs;
        var rec = [];

        for (sym of symbol) {

            console.log("starting wait");
            let val = await dummy(Math.random() * 1000);
            console.log("End wait", val);
            }
        }

    });

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `dummy` function is wrong – `setTimeout` doesn't return anything awaitable, so it returns immediately.

A promise-powered `delay` function looks like

```
const delay = timeToWait => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeToWait));
```

so try that instead of your `dummy`, i.e.

```
console.log('hello');
await delay(100);
console.log('world');
```

---

EDIT: all in all, your code should maybe look like

```
const delay = timeToWait => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeToWait));
// Iterate over the minutes off and get aggregate data
const computeAggregate = async (model, sym) => {
  const symbols = await model
    .find({ symbol: sym })
    .sort({ trade_ts: 1 })
    .exec();
  const currentMinute = symbols[0].minutes_offs;
  for (let sym of symbols) {
    await delay(Math.random() * 1000);
    console.log("End wait", val);
  }
};
```

so you're not mixing `await` and `.then()`.

Comment: Correct, so it's obvious that I am not correctly resolving the promises for my "real" function. It seems to me that the mongoose find is run and then the function exits instead of waiting for the await inside the callback.

Comment: @user2130951 Well, you're also mixing await and `.then()` in rather the curious way... Let me amend my answer a little.

Comment: Agreed. The main problem in the real code was that I had to use promise.all to wait for the loop to gather all information.

Answer (score 0):

`dummy` resolves immediately because a promise it returns and `setTimeout` aren't related. `setTimeout` doesn't return a promise that could be `await`ed. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39496056/3731501), a delayed promise should be:

```
const dummy = async(timeToWait) => {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeToWait));
    console.log("I am waiting for", timeToWait);
    return true;
}
```